# Add list of objects to List<List<Objects>> if not contain

Tags: c#

I have `List<List<Vertex>>` , `Vertex` has a property `id`. I need to add `List<Vertex>>` into this list, but not duplicate lists.

```
 public void AddComponent(List<Vertex> list)
{
    List<List<Vertex>> components = new List<List<Vertex>>;

    //I need something like
      if (!components.Contain(list)) components.Add(list);
}
```

Comment: You first need to define what you mean by equality of two `List<Vertex>`. Are two lists equal if they contain vertices with the same ids? Does the order matter?

Comment: What is the definition of "duplicate list"? Items count, items with the same ids? The same order?

Comment: (<1,2,3,4>,<1,3,2,4>) duplicate

Comment: if it is equal id and count of lists.

Comment: you should read this.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
public void AddComponent(List<Vertex> list)
{
    var isInList = components.Any(componentList =>
    {
        // Check for equality
        if (componentList.Count != list.Count)
            return false;

        for (var i = 0; i < componentList.Count; i++) {
            if (componentList[i] != list[i])
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    });

    if (!isInList)
        components.Add(list);
}
```

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < componentList.Count; i++)

Comment: Thanks; have spent too much time in javascript lately :-)

Comment: if(componentList[i].id != list[i].id) if i want to compare id.

Comment: Yep; essentially you can do whatever you need to do to compare two Vertex instances inside the .Any check.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SequenceEqual - (this means the order must also be the same):

```
if (!components.Any(l => l.SequenceEqual(list))) 
    components.Add(list);
```

Comment: Agreed; this is a better solution, but I wasn't sure what was meant by "duplicate" so I wanted to leave the equality testing open.